# Python how to delete all files from a folder. Not to delete the folder

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of folders with files in the following path: C:\AutoTest\engine\Scv\Projects

In the Projects folder there are folders with files.
E.g. Projects\selenium_project1\files
     Projects\Python_project1\files
     etc.

I would like to delete all the folders from the Projects folders and files.
e.g. I would like to delete selenium_project1\files and Python_project1\files etc.

I have found the following code to delete files.  I am not sure if this will do it correctly.
Will the code below delete the folders and files from the Projects directory?

```
import os, shutil
folder = '/path/to/folder'
for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
    try:
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            os.unlink(file_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Why not replace `os.unlink(file_path)` with `print(file_path)` and see what would be deleted? And no, it won't delete the folders, only the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it in the following way.  My code function is below:

```
@staticmethod
def deleteProjects():
    #projects = os.listdir(os.path.join(ENGINE_DIR, r"scv\Projects"))
    ENGINE_DIR = r"C:\AutoTest\engine"
    projects = os.listdir(os.path.join(ENGINE_DIR, r"scv\Projects"))
    for project in projects:
        logging.error("Project %s not deleted" % project)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.join(ENGINE_DIR, r"scv\Projects"), project)
        print "*** path ***"
        print path
        shutil.rmtree(path)
```